# How to pass GoogleSignInClient instance from one activity to another

Tags: android

I am trying to implement signout for Google Sign-In for android(https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) by passing 
GoogleSignInClient from one activity to another.

I have implemented Google SignIn in android: i.e. in one activity I created GoogleSignInOptions object with DEFAULT_SIGN_IN parameter and used GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by GoogleSignInOptions. So Google signin is working fine. In another activity I want to implement signout functionality like below.

mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

}

Not able to access GoogleSignInClient instance through getParcelableExtra. Its returning null.

How can I pass GoogleSignInClient instance from one activity to another.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass google sign in client in intent.

You should create another google sign in client object in the activity you want sign out functionality.

```
    private void signOut() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void> 
         () {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                // ...
            }
        });
       }
```

create sign in client object as follows.
Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address
profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.

```
     GoogleSignInOptions gso = new   
     GoogleSignInOptions.
     Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestEmail()
    .build();


// Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
 mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

Comment: Hi, I did in the same way, but getting following error. java.lang.NullPointerException: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.signOut()' on a null object reference"

Comment: Make sure mGoogleSignInClient is creating or not.Or you may  Just call.   mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();